# Appending an iframe with jquery using a variable src

Tags: jquery, iframe, append

Hey guys I'm trying to add an iframe to a page using append. In firefox it adds an empty iframe but in chrome it works as it should. The empty iframe is appended only when windowLocation is window.location. When I change it to some other url it works fine.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
 var windowLocation = window.location;
 $("body").append('<iframe id="fullFrame" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>');
 $("#fullFrame").attr("src", windowLocation);
});
```

Comment: You are trying to create an infinite embedding loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this looks like this would create a recursion. According to some old specs for framesets, such a frame should be treated as empty in that case: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331#nesting

So maybe Firefox implements this behaviour.

Comment: Why should it create a loop aren't I creating an iframe of the document in the main document? This shouldn't be any different than any other iframe.

Comment: Sorry about that, indeed it won't create a recusion until the iframe is inserted automatically, but according to the specs it's all about the URL, so Firefox probably simply doesn't care about that the frame was inserted by user action.

Comment: I just tested it with document.location.hostname so it returns my domain name and it's still an empty iframe.

Comment: Is the final location using hostname any different than the current documents location? Using a URL that points to any other resource on the same domain works fine for me. And just to rule it out, is your server maybe sending an `X-Frame-Options` header set to `DENY`?

Comment: Yeah it actually did work fine... I think you're right about that specs thing. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

One might ask why you're embedding a copy of your own web page in itself?  This could create some sort of infinite nesting problem which the browser may be attempting to prevent.  The iframe embeds itself in itself which embeds itself in itself which never stops until all memory or other resources are exhausted unless your code or the browser prevents this from happening.

As for cleaning up the code, I would suggest changing to this code:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
 var windowLocation = window.location.href;
 $("body").append('<iframe id="fullFrame" src="' + windowLocation + '"width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>');

});
```

This changes two things.  First, it uses the `href` property from the location object to get the URL and second, it creates and inserts the iframe with the `.src` property already in place.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. My code actually looked like this but I saw someone here on stackoverflow adding an attribute after the adding of the iframe. Anyway this still does not work. My project is very specific that is why I am doing this.

Comment: @ChristianIvanov - you don't seem to understand the infinite embedding problem.  This is attempting to embed the current document in the current document.  When that loads inside the iframe, the iframe'd document will again attempt to embed itself in itself.  When that iframe loads, it will again attempt to embed itself in itself and it will never stop until something forces it to stop embedding or it runs out of resources.

Comment: This is triggered when a button is pressed on the main document an iframe within an iframe should occur only when the button in the iframe is pressed again. This is not what's happening. It is embeding an empty iframe and if an iframe loop was the case it wouldn't have worked in Chrome.